# SetTimeout: Queue Events in Order

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to write `triggerActions` so that I can print the `processActions` result in order. What I have below will wait for `Process Action 1` to print first, and then print and wait for `Process Action 2...5`.

```js
function triggerActions(count) {
  let counter = 1
  processAction(counter, fn)

  function fn(string) {
    console.log(string)

    if (counter >= count) {
      return
    }
    counter++
    processAction(counter, fn)
  }

}

function processAction(i, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback("Processed Action " + i);
  }, Math.random() * 1000);
}

triggerActions(5);
```

```
/**
 * Result---
 * Processed Action 1
 * Processed Action 2
 * Processed Action 3
 * Processed Action 4
 * Processed Action 5
 */
```

However, I want `triggerActions` to do something like this:

```
/** Process action 3 // log nothing
 * Process action 2 // log nothing
 * Process action 1   // log processed Action 1, process action 2, ...
 * Process action 4 // log process action 4
 * process action 5 // log process action 5
 */
```

Comment: how/where/when is `processAction` called? the code you've shown is far too vague and incomplete to help. What are "queued actions", what are "remaining strings"?

Comment: Please provide more clarity to the question. What do you mean by "remaining strings"?

Comment: Updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: some further explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use promises to chain multiple parallel async requests back into a linear order.  Start by collecting a promise for each, then do something to chain them together (in this case I used reduce).

```js
async function triggerActions(count) {
  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve) => 
      processAction(i, resolve)
    ));
  }
  promises.reduce((a, b) => a.then(console.log).then(() => b)).then(console.log);
}

function processAction(i, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`Completed ${i}`)
    callback(`Processed Action ${i}`);
  }, Math.random() * 1000);
}

triggerActions(5);
```

Comment: Thank you Seph! I finally understand what is happening here. Q:  Is there a way to do this without Promises?

Comment: You could maybe pass in two callbacks... but seriously, if you're going to work with asynchronous code at all, Promises are worth your time to learn.  I promise.